# Deserialize Unknown Type

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I have the following XML:

```
<property name="someName" value="someValue" />
```

Alternatively, this could be:

```
<property name="someName" value="5" />
```

Or:

```
<property name="someName" value="true" />
```

And so on...

```
[Serializable]
[XmlType("property")]
public class Property
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("value")]
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public Property()
    {

    }
}
```

The above code does not work. I can use string, or anything specific as long as it is always that specific type. I was hoping object would allow any known type work.

Comment: String would work for all those situations but you'd have to treat it as a string throughout your app. Is that not an option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It simply isn't possible to use object as data type for attributes with the XmlSerializer unless you implement custom serialization using the [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) interface and manually deal with the situation. If you were not serializing the Value property as an attribute you could have used the [`XmlInclude`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute.aspx) to specify possible known types (such as int, bool, string, ...) and the serializer will emit an additional attribute on the XML to specify the exact type so that it knows how to deserialize. But all this doesn't apply to your scenario because you are using an attribute. It is unfortunate but you will have to either rethink your XML structure or use custom serialization. The XmlSerializer simply cannot deal with this situation.

Another possibility is to define this property as String and do post-serialization-processing. Maybe even define another property on the model that will have only a getter and that based on the value of this string might attempt to parse it to some underlying type.

Answer (score 1):

Well, how would the xml serializer know whether you want to store the string "5" or the actual number 5? You either need to implement the `IXmlSerializable` interface or you might be able to do apply a workaround:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlType("property")]
public class Property
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("value")]
    public string StringValue { get; set; }

    private object _Value;
    [XmlIgnore]
    public object Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (_Value == null)
            {
                 _Value = CreateFromStringValue();
            }
            return _Value;
        }
    }

    public Property()
    {
    }

    private object CreateFromStringValue()
    {
       // parse StringValue in here as you see fit (e.g. first try bool, then int, float, etc.)
    }
}
```

Not as nice but might be all you need.